# Change WAN port to WL0 interface?

Tags: router, lan, dd-wrt, wan

I just installed DD-WRT on my Linksys E3000 router. I've never used this firmware before. I checked the Bandwidth tab, which shows that the WAN interface is getting about 7Mbps bandwidth, while the wl0 interface where my physical network is connected gets roughly 1Mbps.

Is there a way to connect my network to the WAN so i can enjoy that 7Mbps?.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, WL0 is the wifi Interface, not your WAN port

Comment: Yes i get that. But i'm just wondering why there's such a huge difference between both bandwidths. Is this how it's supposed to be..?

Comment: It depends on what client is doing under the wi-if interface.

Comment: @Bilo sorry i don't understand what you mean...?

Comment: word get swapped :$ I mean it depends on the wireless clients is doing what task under the wi-if interface. Let say if it is sharing a file from `ComputerA` to `ComputerB` on the same LAN , all traffic is route through the wifi interface but not the WAN Interface

Comment: Your `WL0` is like the `ath0` in my answer. If I'm not mistaken, it's a short for WLAN. *Don't we just love acronyms and abbreviations...* Unless it's `WL0.1` in which case it's a virtual wireless network, the same thing as VLAN, but only wireless... W... VLAN... WVLAN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading it wrong! An "interface" is not necessarily a physical thing that you can touch with your hands, and with *ports* and connectors on it that you can plug things into. The "WL0" interface is a software component inside the router firmware. It's one part of the holy grail, otherwise known as *Das Code!* For you see, WL0 communicates with other software components inside the firmware, and they are all interconnected and they are entangled in one way or another, and sometimes in more than one way... and when put together, they get you connected to *Das Internet.* To understand how these components communicate; how they do it, what they do it with, what they to themselves and what they do to each other, we need to study the source code *(holy grail)*. But that is beyond the scope of this post, and this site.

- LAN is not even an interface. Not physical interface (hardware), nor
  a virtual interface (software). It's an acronym for Local Area
  Network. It's an umbrella term that encompasses all the local
  computers on the network. By convention, it only describes computers
  that are connected with a network cable.
- The acronym WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network) is used for computers
  that connect to the network wirelessly. Even when they are connected
  to the same network and are on the same subnet as their cabled
  neighbors. In DD-WRT, this is referred to simply as "Wireless". This
  is your WL0 you mentioned.
- WAN is yet another acronym *(because two were not enough)*. It stands
  for Wide Area Network. This is the side of a networked device (i.e.
  router or switch) that is interfacing with another physical network.
  This other network can be either on-premise (in our own house), or
  off-premise (in the wild). In this time and age, for most home or
  office users this is *Das Internet*, and it is beyond our control.
  This is also sometimes referred to as ISP, which stands for Internet
  Service Provider *(can't hurt with some more acronyms)* because they
  are in control of that side of the network. The ISP itself needs to
  interface with other such networks to create the bigger picture...
  *Das Internet!*

So now that we are equipped with some basic understanding of things, let's have a look at a real example. I will be using real data, from the Bandwidth tab of the DD-WRT web UI on my own router.

**Incomming traffic**

Here I am downloading a file using HTTP. The data stream is coming in on the WAN side, hence the green color in the diagram. It reads about 120 Mbps. It is routed to the LAN side.

[image: wan]

**Outgoing traffic**

Here it is coming out on the LAN side. It reads about 120 Mbps. Don't confuse this for being the client computer that is downloading the file. This diagram shows the traffic as it passes through the router. The router is sending the data *out* to the connected computer on LAN side. This is why it's colored red.

[image: lan]

[image: eth0]

Make note of the two diagrams above. One is titled **LAN** and the other is titled **LAN (eth0)**. The "eth" is a short for "ethernet". You can see that one is displaying 92 Mbps and one is displaying 16 Mbps. Even though both diagrams were screen captured at the same time. They should be displaying the same number. This may be because they were not updated simultaneously. But one diagram is basically the sum of all the others. In other words, the **LAN** diagram displays the *total* bandwidth of eth0+n.

I'm not quite sure why I have two diagrams, where only one diagram would be enough. Maybe because the designers thought that two is always better than one. Well, not really... it only shows that there is room for improving the code. Because there are dd-wrt routers with more than one physical LAN (ethernet) interface *(a.k.a. PHY)*. But mine has only one. So dd-wrt should be able to sense that, and only display **LAN (eth0)**, in order to stay consistent with the way that it displays WAN bandwidth (see diagram above and make not of "eth1").

**Wireless traffic**

Here is my wireless traffic. Otherwise known as "Wireless", or "Wi-Fi", or "wiFi", or even "wifi". But nevertheless, it's WLAN. As you can see I don't have a lot of going on there. It's pretty much at a standstill.

[image: ath0]

[image: ath1]

I don't know which is which, but one is for 2.4 GHz band and the other is for 5 GHz. So that's why you see both ath0 and ath1. The "ath" part here is a short for Atheros *(don't we just love weird abbreviations and acronyms)*.

Compared to the LAN diagrams, there should be a third diagram for wireless in this case. One titled **Wireless** only, that sums up bandwidths of ath0+ath1+n. In order to stay consistent. But I guess they didn't think that far. Consistency is one key to making elegant, and easy to read user interfaces. But dd-wrt is still awesome! If you know how to use it and read its diagrams.

**To sum up the sums now...**

```
WAN (eth1) = LAN (eth0) + Wireless (ath0) + Wireless (ath1)
WAN (eth1) = LAN (eth0) + Wireless (ath0 + ath1)
WAN = LAN + Wireless
```

*Perhaps a picture (diagram) says it the best:*

[image: diagram]

Comment: the fact you have a reputation of over 10k does not exonerate us from up-voting yet another great answer of yours